# Python threading queue is very slow

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading, pyzmq

I acquire samples (integers) at a very high rate (several kilo samples per seconds) in a thread and `put()` them in a `threading.Queue`. The main thread `get()`s the samples one by one into a list of length 4096, then `msgpack`s them and finally sends them via ZeroMQ to a client. The client shows the chunks on the screen (print or plot). In short the original idea is, fill the queue with single samples, but empty it in large chunks.

*Everything works 100% as expected.* But the latter part i.e. accessing the queue is very very **slow**. Queue gets larger and the output always lags behind by several to tens of seconds.

My question is: how can I do something to make queue access faster? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you sure your bottleneck is queue operations and not the client operation?

Comment: `collections.deque` is much faster  than `threading.Queue` and also threadsafe but does not have all the features. Maybe `multiprocessing.dummy` (which actually uses threads) is worth a look, too for you.

Comment: You could produce complete `list`s with 4096 samples in the sampling-thread and then put those lists as single items in the Queue - this would require less comparably slow calls to Queue-methods.

Comment: @aph yes, I could check that, in that I temporarily sent data directly from the sampling thread to the client. Though not totally fast, it was much faster than with `queue`, but comes at the cost of loss of samples of course.

Comment: @janbrohl : making lists on the sampling thread **greatly** improved the speed! It nearly perfect now. Thanks so much for the hint! I also changed the chunk size. The speed seems to be also dependent on the chunk size. It seems that the optimum chunk size is 1024, not more not less. I am going to check your other suggestion on `queue` and `multiprocessing` to see if it can get any better.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q :** *"Is there a better approach?"*

**A :**
Well, my ultimate performance-candidate would be this :

- the sampler will operate two or more, separate, statically preallocated "circular"-buffers, one for storing in phase one, the other thus free-to get sent and vice-verse
- once the sampler's filling reaches the end of the first buffer, it starts filling the other, sending the first one and vice versa
- ZeroMQ zero-copy, zero-blocking `.send( zmq.NOBLOCK )` over an `inproc://` transport-class uses just memory-pointer mapping, without moving data in-RAM ( or we can even further reduce the complexity, if moving the filled-up buffer right from here directly to the client, w/o any mediating party ( if not needed otherwise ) for doing so, if using a pre-allocated, static storage,
  like a `numpy.array( ( bufferSize, nBuffersInRoundRobinCYCLE ), dtype = np.int32 )`, we can just send an already packed-block of `{ int32 | int64 }`-s or other `dtype`-mapped data using `.data`-buffer, round-robin cycling along the set of `nBuffersInRoundRobinCYCLE`-separate inplace storage buffers (used for sufficient latency-masking, filling them one after another in cycle and letting them get efficiently `.send( zmq.NOBLOCK )`-sent in the "background" ( behind the back of the Python-GIL-lock blocker tyrant ) in the meantime as needed ).

Tweaking Python-interpreter, disabling `gc.disable()` at all and tuning the default GIL-lock smooth processing "meat-chopper" from `100[ms]` somewhere reasonably above, as no threading is needed anymore, by `sys.settimeinterval()` and moving several acquired samples in lump multiples of CPU-words ~up~to~ CPU-cache-line lengths ( aligned for reducing the fast-cache-to-slow-RAM-memory cache-consistency management mem-I/O updates ) are left for the next LoD of bleeding performance boosting candidates